# Background process in android is killed after a phone call or after long time in the background

Tags: android, google-maps

Currently i am doing a project where i have to trace the path in the Google Map. When the app is in background, after long time when i try to resume the app, everything will be lost.The activity is recreated. Also when a phone call is received, same thing happens. 
I have tried using SharedPreferences. It works only when the app is kept in background for less time.
How can i get rid of this ?

Comment: Take a look at implementing background services

Answer (score 2):

You can't... this is how the Android OS works. It can kill background processes at any time when memory is low.

See [Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) and [Activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html) for more info.

Comment: So what will you suggest further in this situation.

Comment: Save the activity's state in `onSaveInstanceState()`. See [Saving Activity State](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#SavingActivityState).

Comment: onSaveInstanceState() is useful for the state of the UI, but not of everything going on in the activity. The OP might be better off considering creating a Service (or IntentService), spinning of a background worker thread (likely via AsyncTask, Executors or IntentService rather than directly) and keeping that Service alive. But to choose between these options, the OP should certainly spend a lot of time reading the sites Alex L. already gave to learn about lifecycle management.

Comment: The OP indicated in his original post that he wants to save a path in a map... this should be saved as part of the activity's state inside `onSaveInstanceState()`.